# Hurricane IPv6 buffer space error

Tags: networking, ipv6

I am trying to set up a Hurricane IPv6 tunnel on my Ubuntu 11.10 computer. I have set up my **/etc/network/interfaces** file as stated on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6#Get_connected_with_Hurricane_Electric.

My **/etc/network/interfaces** file is the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
      endpoint 209.51.161.14
      address  2001:470:1f06:6::2/64
      netmask  64
      up ip -6 route add default dev he-ipv6
      down ip -6 route del default dev he-ipv6
```

When I try to start IPv6 by running **sudo ifup he-ipv6**, I receive the following:

```
add tunnel sit0 failed: No buffer space available
Failed to bring up he-ipv6.
```

I have double checked that the data I entered from Hurricane is correct. What is causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Problem 1: the `/64` on the end of the `address` parameter is incorrect. That's what the `netmask` parameter is for; you should delete the /64 on the end of `address`.

However, the error you're seeing is what you'd expect if there was already a tunnel configured with the name "he-ipv6". At a guess, you've already run `ifup he-ipv6`, and it's got as far as creating the tunnel before falling over with an error due to the trailing `/64`. Try doing

```
sudo ip tun del he-ipv6
```

to delete the half-configured tunnel before trying again.

Comment: I followed your instructions. Running sudo ifup he-ipv6 now works, but test-ipv6.com doesn't detect any IPv6 address, saying that IPv6 only websites will apear to be down for me. What have I done wrong? Also, what should I set the method to under the IPv6 tab of my wired network settings?

Comment: For the last part of your question, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6#Get_connected_with_Hurricane_Electric seems to have quite specific instructions - I'd start there.

For the first part, I'd try `traceroute6 ipv6.google.com` and see what's going on. Do you have any iptables rules (or an upstream firewall) which could be blocking the tunnel traffic?

Comment: Oops, I missed that last part of the instructions at Ubuntu Wiki. IPv6 is still not working for me. I don't have any firewalls or iptables rules that are blocking the tunnel. When I run the traceroute, it slowly prints out the following:                         http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/868333/

Comment: So traffic isn't even getting as far as the Hurricane Electric gateway at the other end of the tunnel. Strange. I assume you have double- and triple-checked that the HE tunnel is configured correctly (particularly your public IPv4 address)?  

It might also be informative to see whether you can see anything is picked up by `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 proto ipv6` (replace eth0 by the name of your default ipv4 interface). You'd expect to see the tunnelled traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured this option at home too, with Hurricane. It works! but pay attention the following:

1 - I am using ubuntu 11.10

2 - I disabled my manual configuration and bridge configuration at /etc/network/interfaces and set eth0 just like " auto etho / iface eth0 inet dhcp"

3 - I have followed the configurations video at Hurricane Website http://ipv6.he.net/presentations.php. The video named "Tunnelbroker.net Tour & Tunnel Creation"

4 - Unless you set the Public Ip of your ISP ( because I don't have a static puclic IP), you need to set YOUR end point IP (LAN) in this parameter **"endpoint 209.51.161.14"**, for example.... # ifconfig

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW f4:6d:04:d0:db:e3  
     inet end.: 192.168.25.22  Bcast:192.168.25.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
```

So do: "endpoint 192.168.25.22"

I have confgured my ipv6 address like route2...copy the comands and paste in the shell, no in the interfaces configuration file.